# GParted telling me minimum and maximum partition size are equal

Tags: gparted

I'm trying to run GParted to install a linux partition on a windows machine. I'm booting from a live disk and running the installer from there, and the partition is unmounted, yet I can't seem to modify it. (It's the windows data partition, which I need to shrink significantly.)

Comment: It is best to use Windows native tools (while booted to Windows) to manipulate Windows data and system partitions.

Comment: That worked, thanks!